# rm with ampersand in the end and without

Tags: linux, bash, makefile, scripting

This is an interview question I was asked.

Say that you have a large script file, used for compiling and cleaning purposes. Also assume that you have folder named `folder` at the same directory of this file. In addition, in the end of this file you have the following code lines:

```
clean:
    rm -r -f folder &
```

when you try to clean a project, assume it works fine. However, if we remove the ampersand and write this:

```
clean:
    rm -r -f folder
```

then after you try to clean, you'll get the following error:

```
rm: cannot remove 'folder': Directory not empty
```

But if you try to clean one more time, folder will be cleaned as desired.

I needed to find all possible reasons how could this happen. The only thing that I could think of is if we have some race between few threads running this script. Then I was asked- "what if only one thread run the code?"
I didn't see how could this problem happen with one thread- but it seems that I was mistaken and I don't know why. **What other scenarios can cause the error above?**

Edit: in the interview, I could also assume the following:
(1). There are no ampersands in other places at the script file, but the `rm` code line that I wrote.
(2). New files are not created in `folder` while performing rm

Comment: Are you sure you didn't confuse the with `&`/without `&` scenarios?  That is, the scenario with the `&` will occasionally show a failure? Do you use the `&` in other places in the makefile?

Comment: Nope, I didn't confuse. And I could assume that I have no ampersand in other places at the script file.

Comment: Could some other process write a new file to `folder` while `rm -r -f` still deletes the folder?

Comment: Lukas, I could assume that new files are not created in it while performing rm.

Comment: This is not related with the `&` but with some process creating files under `folder/.` while you invoke the `rm`.

It works if you run it again because there is no other process writing files there.

Comment: Navarro, that's a possible scenario, but as I wrote- I can assume that new files are not created in it while performing rm

Comment: @John, how do you ensure this?

Comment: @FlorianWeimer, I don't need to ensure it. This is an assumption that was made by the interviewer

Comment: Any idea what OS and version of rm the interviewer was using? It's possible (i.e., I seem to remember a version of rm that did this) that `rm -fr folder` and `rm -fr folder &` behave the same way, both failing to completely remove the directory if it can't be completely emptied, but differ in that the `&` version might not output an error message because it saw that it was running without a terminal on its stdin.

Comment: @MarkPlotnick - the OS is cygwin. The call to rm was like this: '@rm'

Answer (score 1):

I'm glad this is a fictional problem.   Using `&` this way in makefiles is completely bogus; hopefully no one is doing that in the real world.

Anyway, in a typical interview scenario, you need to guess the answer the interviewer has in their script. It's likely that problem is described incorrectly, at least in your question (and it wouldn't be unusual if the wrong scenario was presented in the interview, too).  The question makes some theoretical sense if the error message happens with the `&` present and you run `make clean all`.  Then, the new build creates files which prevent removal of the directory.  And that's why you should not use `&` in makefile recipes.

Comment: "hopefully no one is doing that in the real world": Would be nice if you were right. However, I have learned to distrust the sanity and rationality of people. What can be done, will be done by some. Whether it makes sense or not. And those who do it will assert that it's obviously the right thing to do, of course!

Comment: After the interviewer asked me this question, he showed me relevant code on a computer to the scenario described. I saw that you get an error when not using &,  and don't get error if you use & (compiled and cleaned to see that). The interviewer told me that this question is based on real issue they had in the company: someone used & in the company code like described, and no one noticed till recently. When they noticed- they understood that it's not a good habit - and wanted to see why they don't get an error using & and get error when not using &. So I don't think my description is incorrect

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK, in a shell, when a process run in background, you can not get the status of the process. The process may run indifinitely -- maybe a few hours. Only foreground process will give you exit code. So, `make` will never able to check status of any command with ampersand. Check the following:

```
% true
% ls /non-exist-file &
% echo $?
```

Answer (score 0):

I can only assume one single reason for the question: they are on Mac OS X and and hit an old bug with HFS+ where the `readdir()` system call yielded incorrect results on some occasions. They just wanted to know if you know about it (see: https://www.postgresql.org/message-id/51549ea20911051659j62a3959ct8b2f2e702953cf83@mail.gmail.com )

Their workaround, however, appears bogus. Pushing a failing `rm` call to background to avoid `make` gaining knowledge about the failure isn't a fix. Prepending the line with `-` would have had the same result and while avoiding possible race conditions.